# Delete the id name added in second click

Tags: javascript, html

I made an application to select seats in HTML and JS, but I want that when I pick a seat the Id gets displayed in an h3 tag and when you click it again the text of that id gets removed

this is a shortened version of my html the original has more rows and columns:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var seatsUnclicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
  var seatsClicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seatClicked");
  var images = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
  var seatsOutput = document.getElementById("seatsOutput");


  for (let i = 0; i < seatsUnclicked.length; i++) {

    seatsUnclicked[i].onclick = function() {

      this.classList.add("new")

      if ($(this).hasClass('seatClicked')) {

        //Code to remove the ID added goes here

        this.classList.remove("seatClicked")
        this.classList.remove("new")
        this.src = "chair.svg";

      }

      if ($(this).hasClass('new')) {
        seatsOutput.innerHTML += ' ' + this.id
        this.src = "chairclicked.svg";
        this.classList.add("seatClicked")
        this.classList.remove("new")

      }

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A7" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
</div>
<h2>Seats chosen:<span id="seatsOutput"></span></h2>
```

Comment: `new` class is always added and then removed in the same function call

Comment: and what is the issue btw ?

Comment: If you click on a seat it changes the seat color to green and displays the id of the seat in the tag  <span id="seatsOutput"> and if you click it again the seat goes back to black and its supposed to delete the display  added when you clicked it first but I dont know how to code that part.

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50376303/6804958) answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the text of `span` tag and update it

Something like

```
var seats = seatsOutput.textContent.split(" ");

seats.splice(seats.indexOf(this.id),1);

seatsOutput.textContent = seats.join(" ")
```

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var seat = document.getElementById("seats");
for(var i=0; i< divs.length; i++){
  divs[i].addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("red");
    
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('red')){
    var seats = seat.textContent.split(" ");

    seats.splice(seats.indexOf(this.id),1);

    seat.textContent = seats.join(" ")
    
    }else{
    
    seat.textContent+=' '+e.target.id;
    
    }
    

  })
}
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}

#seats{

height: 30px;
border : solid 1px;

}
```

```html
<div class="test" id="1">1</div>
<div class="test" id="2">2</div>
<div class="test" id="3">3</div>

<br/><br/>
<span id="seats"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the document and re-print on each click:

```js
let isClicked = (seat) => (seat.classList.contains("seatClicked"));
let seatsOutput = document.getElementById("seatsOutput");
let printCurrentSeats = () => {
  seatsOutput.innerHTML = "";
  let seatsClicked = document.getElementsByClassName("seatClicked");
  for (let i = 0; i < seatsClicked.length; i++) {
    seatsOutput.innerHTML += " " + seatsClicked[i].id;
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  let seats = document.getElementsByClassName("seat-unique");
  for (let i in seats) {
    seats[i].onclick = function() {
      if (isClicked(this)) {
        this.classList.remove("seatClicked");
        printCurrentSeats();
        this.src = "chair.svg";
      }
      else {
        this.classList.add("seatClicked");
        printCurrentSeats();
        this.src = "chairclicked.svg";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique hola " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A7" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
</div>
<h2>Tickets elegidos:<span id="seatsOutput"></span></h2>
```

This is a pretty straight-forward solution, but if I had more seats (or if the order matters) I'd store a JS array with the current chosen seats, so I don't need to go through all the HTML elements on every click.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Improve your code by using else if condition.

```css
if ($(this).hasClass('seatClicked')) {
  //Code to remove the ID added goes here
  this.classList.remove("seatClicked") this.classList.remove("new") this.src="chair.svg";
}

else if($(this).hasClass('new')) {
  seatsOutput.innerHTML+=' '+this.idthis.src="chairclicked.svg";
  this.classList.add("seatClicked") this.classList.remove("new")
}

else {
  this.classList.add("new")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use jquery and pure javascript mixed and it is not a good practice. Choose one of them.

**$(this).toggleClass("seatClicked");** will toggle a class to an element.

**$(".seat-unique").each()** function iterates all selected elements.

**$(this).attr('id')** gives you the id of selected element.

**$(this).on('click', function() {})** add an event to elements you want.

Look this code. Hope this helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".seat-unique").each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("seatClicked");
      $("#seatsOutput").text($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  })

});
```

```css
.seatClicked {
  border: 1px solid #00ff00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seats-row-A">
  <img id="A1" class="seat-unique hola" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A2" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A3" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A4" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A5" class="seat-unique" src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A6" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
  <img id="A7" class="seat-unique " src="chair.svg">
</div>
<h2>Tickets elegidos:<span id="seatsOutput"></span></h2>
```